# Is there a way to check if any fields in a global set have content?

Tags: conditional

I have a global set called socialNetworkContent.

Is there a way to setup a conditional to check whether any of the fields within this set have content?

So the section wouldn't display if all the fields were blank.

Something along these lines:

```
{% if socialNetworkContent|length %}
<section>
<div class="social">
    <h1>Follow Us</h1>
    <ul>
            {% if socialNetworkContent.branchFacebookProfile|length %}<li><a href="{{ socialNetworkContent.branchFacebookProfile }}"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
            {% if socialNetworkContent.branchTwitterAccount|length %}<li><a href="{{ socialNetworkContent.branchTwitterAccount }}"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
            {% if socialNetworkContent.branchLinkedInAccount|length %}<li><a href="{{ socialNetworkContent.branchLinkedInAccount }}"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
            {% if socialNetworkContent.branchGooglePlusAccount|length %}<li><a href="{{ socialNetworkContent.branchGooglePlusAccount }}"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
            {% if socialNetworkContent.branchInstagramAccount|length %}<li><a href="{{ socialNetworkContent.branchInstagramAccount }}"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
            {% if socialNetworkContent.branchYoutubeAccount|length %}<li><a href="{{ socialNetworkContent.branchYoutubeAccount }}"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
</section>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly "quick", you'll have to do something like this:

```
{% if socialNetworkContent.branchFacebookProfile|length 
       or socialNetworkContent.branchTwitterAccount|length
       or socialNetworkContent.branchLinkedInAccount|length
       ...
%}
```

Which is probably exactly what you're trying to avoid.

If you want to just make it a little easier to read, you can do something like this:

```
{% set x = socialNetworkContent %}

{% if x.branchFacebookProfile|length 
       or x.branchTwitterAccount|length
       or x.branchLinkedInAccount|length
       ...
%}
```

The hurdle that you're dealing with is the fact that the `socialNetworkContent` object contains many other attributes besides just your custom field names. So there's not really any efficient way to "loop through" your custom fields without dealing with a bunch of extra junk.

Of course, you could build a plugin to create a simple boolean variable, but that sounds like overkill for this situation.